# Pivot Excel VBA, Error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a Pivot Table using VBA, but I get an error in the following line:

```
Sheets("Done").PivotCaches.Add _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:=Range("A1").CurrentRegion).CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:="R4C" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + 3
```

I get an error stating:

> Error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: `PivotCaches` is a property of the workbook, not a worksheet.